# Eclipse Pydev project python grammar version 3 but run in version 2

Tags: debian, python, eclipse, python3, version

I am under Eclipse Pydev 3.8.1 (fresh install of Eclipse Pydev package under Debian 9). I have created a project with python grammar 3.0:

[image]

But when I run it and check the version, I have python version 2.7.13:

```
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=13, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

What have I done badly ? Besides, I would expect to be able to use version 3.5.3 which is installed on my system.

Answer (score 0):

I could find an answer [here](https://www.linuxrouen.fr/wp/programmation/developpement-python-avec-eclipse-et-pydev-introduction-21165/) (in french):

> PyDev has to be configured to use the right Python version available on the system. In Eclipse Workbench Menu -> Windows -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreter -> Click on `New…` -> Inside the "*Select interpreter*" GUI window, fill the field `Interpreter Name:` with e.g. "*Python v.3.5*" and the field `Interpreter Executable:` with the executable you want as */usr/bin/python3.5* or use the browse feature. Then valid with `OK` button.